Find the missing number in bidimensional array
I m trying to write a Python code that make the following step.
I set a value of frame like this:
minFrame = 0
maxFrame = 30

Now I have a bidimensional array like this:
a = [[]]

In that array I could have this situation for example:
a= [[2,5],[10,20]]

The Python code should to find the missing part and should to return me the following array (for example).
missingArray = [[0,1],[6,9],[21,30]]

How can I develop a similar algorithm?

Please show us your attempts.

I need an algorithm that return me missingArray as result.

?? Did you even read my other comment? Please [edit] your question to show us your attempts ----> How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?

I think you mean to do this:
minFrame = 0
maxFrame = 30

a = [[2,5],[10,20]]
result = []
pos = 0
for x,y in a:
    if pos == minFrame:
        if x > minFrame:
            result.append([minFrame, x-minFrame-1])
    elif pos < x:
        result.append([pos+1, x-1])
    pos = y
else:
    if pos < maxFrame:
        result.append([pos+1, maxFrame])

print(result)  # [[0, 1], [6, 9], [21, 30]]

